# Wrong filename encoding/decoding when downloading recursively with wget

Tags: linux, centos, wget, encoding

I'm downloading files from a remote directory recursively using `wget` and whoever created the folders and files, used special characters such as `è` or `Ó`, when I download a single specificating the full path+filename, the file is downloaded with it's name correctly, but when I just try to download the folder with all the files and directories using the option `-r` the filenames are not encoded or decoded correctly.

From what I've gathered, the filename gets sent as an `ascii` in the request, and both my machine and the server have `UTF-8` encoding on the `$PATH`, so it should not be an issue with it either.

When the wget creates the file, the `è` character (which I will be using as an example) in the filename is saved as a `\350` in octal character code, and it appears as a `Ã¨`. And this only happens when I download the files recursively, if I download this file using the complete URL the filename appears correctly.

I've spent a fair amount of hours looking up Q/A here and there, and I've tried everything I've seen, from setting `--local-encoding` and `--remote-encoding` to `UTF-8`, using the `--restrict-file-names=nocontrol`, etc.

The ports 21 and 22 are closed, so I can't download the files through SCP or FTP, most likely any other protocol to download the files will give the same error, but I'm open to any not common ones that I could use.

Also the main problem I have with this, is that when I download the files, when I try to copy them to a backup folder, some of the files sometimes give me an error of file not found due to the filename being messed up, for now im using the `--restrict-file-names=ascii` and keeping the names in `ascii` as a workaround, but I need to change the encoding to `UTF-8`, also I can't install on the machine any applications such as convmv (orders from the boss).

This is the command I've been using to download the files:
`wget --keep-session-cookies --cookies=on --no-check-certificate --restrict-file-names=nocontrol --convert-links --no-parent -r <URL>`

This is how the file name is saved with downloading a single file vs all files recursively:

`OT14-004 CEIP Pins del VallÃ¨s.vsd`

`OT14-004 CEIP Pins del Vallès.vsd`

I'm using a machine with this distro `CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)`
and with this version of wget `GNU Wget 1.14 built on linux-gnu`

Comment: This seems to be a [known issue](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=411290) in wget. You can try the alternatives listed [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/233882/how-to-download-link-with-unicode-using-wget).

Comment: The solutions there are using `curl` with as far as I know does not works recursively, and `--restrict-file-names=nocontrol`, which as I have mentioned I already tried.